# My matematica notebook dosen't work,its bring syntax error ,why?

Tags: notebooks

i have many matematica notebooks and all of them are working clearly besides one which is the most important for me.There is my whole project.Please someone help me.What should i do???[image]

Comment: The question is what have you done? And without any details I can only say click Yes and take a look.

Comment: Ok thank u,there are my whole project and i don't want to "lose" it

Comment: And NEVER forget to keep backups of previous notebook versions. I've heard so many frightening stories ...

Comment: yes next time i will do it,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mathematica notebook is corrupt](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67030/mathematica-notebook-is-corrupt)

Comment: Usually it is possible to copy quite some bits of useful code from a corrupt notebook using a simple tool as Notepad. And as to corruption: sometimes adding a } at the correct place may be all that is needed.

Answer (score 4):

I had your problem more than once. As @belisarius said, backup, backup backup. Very often that saved my day. However, in some occasions there was no backup. A possible but time consuming way is to *repair* your notebook by hand. I hope it is not to big. Using the solution given in the [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67030/mathematica-notebook-is-corrupt) provided by @Yves-Klett might reduce the file size. Make sure though that you do not overwrite the original. The provided code might not work properly if the code is corrupted and it might delete stuff that you actually want to keep.
That said, the hard way really looks like this.

1. Open the code in a text editor (it is probably better not to use
       *Mathematica for this*)
2. Create a working notebook, save it, and also open it in the text
   editor
3. Copy stuff from (complete expressions of course) the original notebook to the new one and check if it
   is working by loading it in *Mathematica* after each step.

That's a painful job, but worked for me once. Sorry that I cannot help more, but maybe someone else can.

**Update**
Thinking about the comment from @sjoerd-c-de-vries, ("*...sometimes adding a } at the correct place may be all that is needed.*") you might think about taking a text editor that provides a balance check on parenthesis.
In Win you may have a look at Notepad++ in Linux you can take e.g. KWrite or NEdit

Comment: i start do it again,but anyway thank u lot,and  this time i will keep backup

Comment: @Anna, is it a big file? Does it contain a lot of graphics? If you save a small file with similar graphic output, you can have a look on that code, just to see, what you can delete without problem.

Comment: No its some kind of big and i should only work 2 hours to do it all again,