# How to restore corrupted files?

Tags: notebooks

I have a file that I can't reopen because MMa was "Not Responding" and I had to shut it down.

I found links online to this:
http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12423

I executed those two instructions in a new notebook, but no "NotebookRestore dialogue" appeared, whatever that is.

What am I missing here?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=[notebooks]+corrupted

Comment: @belisarius  Not one useful answer in any of that.  I tried Daniel W's CleanNotebookOpen[] program, but the Import[] failed because of the corruption.

Comment: @belisarius  MMa seems to be upset that the file doesn't end properly, so it won't open it at all.  Is there some way I can just pick a spot in the text file and insert an <endoffile> is will like?

Comment: I don't know of anything of general applicability, sorry. Been there a few times with different outcomes.Mostly an artisan trade.

Comment: I'd use a simple ASCII editor to open the file and see whether it would be possible to salvage complete cells from it and perhaps try to close unclosed (because of missing closing brackets) function code.

Comment: Can you try the following, **but with a copy of your corrupted file**: ``Needs["AuthorTools`"]; NotebookRestore[]``

Comment: @Lou  THAT WORKED!!!  Thank you, you saved me many hours of pain and irritation.  If you want to put that into an Answer, I'll Accept it and your heroism will receive wider acknowledgment.

Comment: @Jerry Guern, I like your your choice of words.

Comment: Be sure to use something like https://github.com/joshburkart/mathematica-autobackup in the future.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try the following, **but with a copy of your corrupted file**:

```
Needs["AuthorTools`"] 
NotebookRestore[]
```

which opens a new window.

N.B.: works on "10.0.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"

Comment: THAT WORKED!  Thank you!

Comment: If you type Import<leftBracket><quote><space> a Browse icon will pop up, then if you click on your corrupt file, MMa will fill in the complete path to the file, which you can then cut-paste into the brackets in NotebookRestore[].

Comment: @JerryGuern there's also the Insert>File path menu

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries  I had a feeling that if I posted my clunky method someone would post something better.  Thank you!

Comment: link to this on the support site http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12423.  One does wonder why the front end doesn't just offer to do this automatically.

Comment: THAT WORKED! Thank you! i do not how wolfram support not change the help  center his page do not work

Comment: thank you so much for this!!!