# I can't open my notebook because the only copy of the .nb file I have has been corrupted

Tags: notebooks, warning-messages

I had to force close my notebook because my computer was counting down to an automatic update and *Mathematica* kept crashing during an evaluation. I'd been working for over a week on the content, but didn't save any backups to a separate file, because I assumed there was an automatic back-up in place.

After the update I tried to reopen my notebook to be greeted with a syntax error message, saying that the notebook could only be opened in plain text. When I opened the file I got the following message:

> "There was a syntax error on line 33594 in the file: Assessed Problems 1.nb.
>   The error was:
>    7-bdc9-f01ad398ed45"]
>
> }, Open  ]],
>
> Cell[CellGroupData[{
>
> Cell[1656773, 32686, 187, 4, 28, "Input",ExpressionUUID->"f1d97f12-7677-4937-93c8-afa8c5c84eac"],
>
> Cell[1656963, 32692, 142, 3, 32, "Output",ExpressionUUID->"fdf1f023-91b6-4629-baad-49bc0bec11c8"]""

How can I fix this? Can anyone help me? I looked at previous questions on the stack exchange network and tried to copy the work to a new notebook and then delete some code and then reformat the cells back to the traditional output, but this isn't working.

I am running *Mathematica* version 11.2.

Comment: Unless it is very long you can open it in a text editor, got through all Cell[BoxData[...], ....], copy them, paste to a new notebook.

Comment: I forget when I had to do this, but maybe it was in such a situation: Copy your file. From within *Mathematica*, do menu File > Open...; select your file (or the copy) AND click on the Options button.  Select "Parse and load entire file" (or something like that).  Then open and see whether it salvages anything.

Comment: Can you post your full notebook?

Comment: @M.R. Your joking, right? You did notice the error occurred on line 33594? The notebook is too big to post here. Maybe it can be posted on Dropbox or a similar sharing site.

Comment: Yup, I meant post a link to Dropbox

Comment: try this $\text{Needs["AuthorTools`"] ;
NotebookRestore[] }$ see [how-to-restore-corrupted-files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92814/how-to-restore-corrupted-files)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help. I ended up taking Nasser's advice and used the notebook restore and got my notebook back minus six lines of corrupted code. I was stressing about it all night so I'm very happy that I got the notebook back. I'll take this as a lesson about saving back up copies of my notebooks.

Comment: Please elaborate on the steps you've taken so others can follow in future.