# Mathematica code got converted to postscript format. Is there a way to restore it?

Tags: format

[image: Snapshot of the present notebook]
I was trying to save my notebook in .pdf format, but instead of that, somehow this happened. How do I restore my notebook? Please Help.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92814/38178)?

Comment: Yes. It did not help. the outcome was the same code

Comment: It looks like you saved a PostScript (not PDF) version of your `prob1.nb` as `probl1.nb` instead of as `prob1.ps`.  If so, the question is whether you are backing up your files (e.g., with [automatic backups](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookAutoSave.html)).

Comment: Yes, this isn't a corruption, but it looks like the file was saved as a format that is not .nb. Unfortunately there isn't a way to convert it back that I am aware of. Hope you've got backups.

Comment: thanks Alan and user6014. This may have happened. Unfortunately, I did not have a backup.

Comment: Could you open the document in a ps/pdf viewer, and then copy the text?

Comment: No, because I can't save it in .pdf or .ps format. It just forms a 0 KB file once I try to do that. @Carl

Comment: It's already in .ps format, just open the file in an application that can read postscript files.

Comment: what you have somehow ended up with is postscript code in a cell in a notebook. Copy the code and paste into a text editor (notepad). Save. Change extension to ".ps" then open with acrobat and see what you have.    Aside, when you originally "saved as" postscript it would have created a copy, still allowing you to save the notebook in native format. (ie you did at least two wrong things to get where you are)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @george2079 but changing extension of a text file like that only saves it as ".ps.txt" format. I also tried selecting the full doc from the .nb file and saving the selection in .eps format, but it seems to be taking too long to generate the file.

Comment: At present it is in .nb format @CarlWoll

Comment: Evaluate that cell, then run `Export["file.ps", %, "String"]` to create a ps file that you can open in a ps/pdf viewer.

Comment: It generates a 1 KB file, which is blank when I open it.@CarlWoll

Comment: i  mean change the extension in the os.