# Mathematica notebook format changed after crash

Tags: notebooks

I had a normal *nb notebook in Mathematica 12 with graphics, calculations, text....but by some uncontrolled click it was broken and now it can be opened only as a notebook with crazy "Mathematica" cells, boxes and so on... Is there any way to recover the file in normal form? The notebook looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GxfDzqAqGelyKZ4ZlKK4x013jTUC2-bu/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92814)?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn´t work...

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2194484).

Comment: So I managed to recover the original notebook (with some annoying modifications like extra spaces between some characters...). Basically, I first transformed the .nb file into a .txt, then I erased some comment lines in the beginning and in the end and finally I copied again the whole and paste it back to a new .nb file.